# hero transition background disappears

Tags: polymer

http://www.polymer-project.org/components/core-animated-pages/demos/music.html

When you change the `.card` height in chrome console you will see that the small card tiles in the background hiding behind the big card, suddenly disappear completely when the animation is done.

Is there a way to tell a hero transition to not remove the parent section? Or a way to make the parent section disappear but gradually?

In this case it is ok because you don't see them disappear but when the background has a number of small cards that do not fit behind the large card it would look way better if they just stay in the background.

EDIT1:

```
#mini {
 display: block !important;
}

#mini *[hero] {
  opacity: 0.5 !important;
}

        <section id="mini">

                <template repeat="{{items as item}}">
                    <div class="chip" hero-id="{{item.id}}" hero?="{{muts === item }}" on-tap="{{transition}}">

                    </div>
                </template>

        </section>
```

EDIT2:

The second hero is not in the middle of the view port anymore when the background chips exceed the screen size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another workaround I found is to add an id and a bit of CSS to the core-animated-pages component.
My core-animated-pages looks like this :

```
<core-animated-pages selected="{{page}}" transitions="hero-transition"
                         on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{complete}}">
    <section id="mini">
        <div class="chip-container" hero-p on-tap="{{transition}}">             
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="chip-container" hero-p on-tap="{{transition}}">
            ...
        </div>
    </section>
    <section id="details">
        ...
    </section>
</core-animated-pages>
```

Nothing special, I just have two lines of "chips". Note the id on the "chip-container container", it's the one that enables us to do some css modification directly in `components/core-animated-pages/core-animated-pages.css`. Those modifications are the following :

```
/*
Enables us to keep the "chip-container container" visible even after the hero transition
*/

*#mini {
display: block !important;
}


/*
Fades out the "chip" that realized a transition ([active] and .core-selected are removed
from the "chip-container container" during the transition)
*/

*#mini *[hero] {
opacity: 0 !important;
}


/* 
Fades in the "chip" when everything goes back to it's original state ([hero] isn't 
removed from the chip, but [active] and .core-selected are re-set on the "chip-container
container", so we use this to distinguish wish state we're in, and so if it's "legit" to 
see the "chip") 
*/

*#mini[active] *[hero] {
opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

Might not be the cleanest way but it works, I hope I explained well enough how I managed to achieve this result, and every tiny part of my solution. Feel free to comment / ask if that's not the case :)

Comment: Note : to make this work properly on google chrome, don't forget to put also the `::content` "duplicate" for css rules (e.g. : `::content *#mini, *#mini { ... }`

Comment: Almost works except when you generate `chip-containers` dynamically there is only one hero `opacity: 0.5`in the background (see edit)

Comment: And the `details` container is not in the middle of the viewport anymore.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `cross-fade-all` to the list of transitions, the background cards will more gracefully fade out, rather than disappearing at the end of the animation:

```
<core-animated-pages
 selected="{{page}}"
 transitions="hero-transition cross-fade-all"
 on-core-animated-pages-transition-end="{{complete}}">
```

You can test it [on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/tukazizeca/1/edit?html,output).

Comment: Nice :) ps Is it possible to stop them from disappearing?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show your .js Code?  You need to remove   object.flush(); from your .js  code. Hope this help.

Comment: I only find Platform.flush() in the polymer animation code?

Comment: @GertCuykens : Will you remove above line and try?

Comment: ok going to try :) just not sure what it does at all or if it does something else also. I will keep you posted.

Comment: Nope does not do anything for me?